# Java JDBC : establish a persistent connection which lasts days

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am currently working on a java project which implements web-scraping and I am facing a weird issue so far.

Here is what I do :

1. Get an URL Connection with a page of a website
2. Parse the HTML code to get some content (OpenData)
3. Add the content in my database
4. Move onto the next page and go back to Step 1

This is actually very long and it can last for days so I need to let the script running. The problem is that sometimes, it stops for no reason (no errors, no messages, no window close ; It just litterally stops and I need to press one of my button to restart it). I have implemented a short code which restarts the application from where it stopped. I believe it's a connection problem to the database so I would like to know how could I fix it.

I use a static class which creates an instance of this class at the beginning of the application and then I use static methods from this class to run my queries like this for example :

```
    ConnexionBDD.con.prepareStatement(query);

public static Connection loadDriver() {
 try {
     Class.forName(Driver);
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionString, user, pwd);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Classe not found : Class.forName(...)");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
return con;
}
```

I am not sure I am doing the right thing to make my connection lasts forever (in theory) and eventually close it when It has finished to iterate over my links.

Comment: *"I believe it's a connection problem to the database"*. Why? Do you have logging that indicates that? Have you attached a debugger to the program when it stops progressing to confirm that? If you examine `pg_stat_activity` and check for your client (tip: set `application_name` so it's easy to find) do you see it, and if so, what's it doig?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I have no idea how to attach a debugger only when it stops progressing because I don't even know where it stops progressing. Actually I see no other options apart from the persistent link with the database but I must be wrong. 
The problem is that I never know when the application will stop progressing. It's not a matter of HTML code/links I am parsing or URL Connection because when I restart the application, it iterates fine where it has previously stopped. I don't know if I am clear :/

Comment: It'd be good if you'd explain how you start and and run the program, how you determine whether it's stopped working, whether the "java" process still exists when it stops working or not, what the error return code is / stderr output is if it actually quits, etc.

Comment: I start the program as a java application. It creates a Window (Swing) with some TextFields (such as URL adress) and a button which starts the web scrapping when pressed. It is supposed to add one page content to the database in 1-2 seconds and then move on to the next page. I determine the stop when it doesn't display anything at all both in the console and in the window (which still remains opened). However the button is still available and if I press it again, it will restart from where it stopped. So no error code, no strderr, no console messages whatsoever.

Comment: OK, so "the button" is a Swing button in your user interface. What's the event that it invokes? What does it do? Anyway, it sounds like you need to spent some time with a debugger and some logging tools, there's no evidence of a database problem here.

Comment: It's an Action Event which instanciantes a Swing Worker class (because the application is going to last). And then It starts getting information from the web pages and querying in my database. I do understand what is a debugger but I Can't know when the program will be "stuck". A debugger is used with breakpoints and I would need to press the "next" button every time. How can I set my debugger to see what's happening without needing to press a button or click somewhere ? When I look at my debug Debug View : everything is empty (variables).

Comment: Er... attach the debugger once the program stops working. That's why I said use a *remote* debugger. Then manually break execution. Or, for that matter, start it under the debugger then tell it to run freely, and pause execution once the program stops working. You don't have to step in a debugger or run to a breakpoint, you can also free-run and manually break. Once you manually break you can see what the program is doing at that moment, and you can step through to see why it doesn't seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're jumping the gun a bit here. There's no evidence that the database connection is actually the problem. Usually if you were having DB connection issues you'd be getting an exception from the connection when you try to perform operations on it, a timeout, etc.

You need to:

- Add detailed logging to your application, so you can see what it's doing as it progresses, and what it's trying to do when it stops; and
- Run it with `-Xdebug` and other suitable options for remote debugging, so you can attach a debugger to it when it stops and examine its state to see what it is doing at the time. Use the debugger user interface from NetBeans, Eclipse, or whatever you prefer to attach to the program when the logging indicates that it's stopped progressing.

For logging, you can use `java.util.logging`. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) and the [logging overview docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html).

Here's an example of [how to do remote debugging with Eclipse](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat). You'll be able to find similar guides for your chosen IDE. Java also has a command line debugger, but it's pretty painful.

You also need to check to see whether the program might be crashing or exiting, rather than just stopping working. You should capture any standard error output from the program and check the program's error return code from the shell. Also look for `hs_error` files in the directory the program runs in, in case there's a JVM crash, though that should generate output on stderr as well.

You should also:

- Set an `application_name` when you establish a connection to PostgreSQL, so you can easily see what your client is doing with the database. You can specify `application_name` as a JDBC connection parameter, or run a `SET application_name = 'blah'` statement after connecting.
- When logging (or however you currently tell that your program is no longer progressing) indicates that the program has stopped working, examine `pg_stat_activity` in the server, looking at the entry/entries for your application. See if the connection is `idle`, `idle in transaction`, or running a statement, and what that statement is. If it's running a statement, query against `pg_locks` to see if it's blocked on an ungranted lock.